# Color conversion between color spaces

Tags: c#, colors

I'm creating a library that allows conversion between the following color spaces:

HSV, HLS, RGB, CMYK, HEX

Up until now, I have the following conversions implemented:

HSV -> HLS

HSV -> RGB

HSV -> CMYK **(HSV -> RGB -> CMYK :: see NB)**

RGB -> HSV

RGB -> HLS

RGB -> CMYK

RGB -> HEX

HLS -> RGB

HLS -> HSV

HLS -> CMYK **(HLS -> RGB -> CMYK :: see NB)**

CMYK -> RGB

CMYK -> HSV **(CMYK -> RGB -> HSV :: see NB)**

CMYK -> HLS **(CMYK -> RGB -> HLS :: see NB)**

**NB:** HSV and HSL can't be directly converted to CMYK because they're not absolute color spaces. They need elements of the RGB space so that the conversion to CMYK is meaningful. ([CMYK color to HSV color directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817720/cmyk-color-to-hsv-color-directly))

Right now, I have to implement all the HEX conversions:

HEX <-> RGB

HEX <-> HSV

HEX <-> HLS

HEX <-> CMYK

Converting between HEX and RGB is simple and I have it implemented. What bothers me are the HEX <-> HSV and HEX <-> HLS conversions. **Is there a direct way to convert HEX to HSV and HSL or do I have to use HEX -> RGB -> HSV/HLS? What about HEX <-> CMYK?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but someone told me HEX is just another representation of RGB. If this is the case, then the above question answers itself.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the HEX values are just HEX representations of each individual channel's values concatenated together. If all of your colors are represented by 8 bits and you are looking for a HEX representation that can be used in HTML it would be like this:

```
Color  8 bit            HEX value
---------------------------------
RGB    255,128,0        FF8000
CMYK   255,128,255,128  FF80FF80
```